# R: How to adjust time scale in hourly plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted to create an hourly plot, the only information on the time is hour in UTC time zone. However, I want the plot to show hour scale in AEST time zone. Here is what I have done

```
Average_value_median <- aggregate(download_speed_normalised_month ~ year+ISP+hour, house_total_filtered, median)
Average_value_median$hour <- as.POSIXct(strptime(Average_value_median$hour, format = "%H"), format = "%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", tz= "UTC")


graph_name = paste(Average_value_median$year[1]," Normalised speed by hour plot (median) ")
SpeedHour_Plot <- ggplot(Average_value_median, aes(x = hour, y = download_speed_normalised_month, color = ISP, shape = ISP, color=supp)) +
  geom_point(size=2.5)+
  geom_line(size=1)+
  ylab("Normalised Download speed") +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = seq(min(Average_value_mean$hour),max(Average_value_mean$hour),"3 hour"),labels = date_format("%H:%M", tz="Australia/Sydney"))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0, 0)) +  
  ggtitle(graph_name)+
  theme_bw()
```

This works perfectly fine but im having a problem with the starting and ending of time scale. The time scale starts at 11:00 and ends at 10:00 (because sydney is UTC+11), however I want the time scale to start at 06:00 and ends at 05:00.

Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks a lot!

[This is the current plot I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1ptW.png)

Comment: I tried `ggplot(dd, aes(hour, dls)) + geom_line()` and then `ggplot(dd, aes(time - 6 * 60 * 60, dls)) + geom_line()` and it worked